# $http inside $http in an angular factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

I have an angular factory that makes an $http call with a get and then.

```
 .factory('DataModel', function($http) {
```

I have a .get.then that works great. The value comes back, and since I originally returned a function to return the factory value, everything updates when it changes.

Now I have to make a dependent call based on the data that returned the first time.

**First try**: $http.get.then inside the outer $http.get.then.

The inner (dependent) call successfully gets the data, but when it updates the factory parameters only the first .get.then is picked up by the calling controller.

**Next try**: $scope.$watch.

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])
 .factory('DataModel', function($scope, $http) {
```

If I put a $scope parameter in there I get an error:

> Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- DataModel

So I can't seem to use the $scope.$watch method.

**Third try**: callbacks?

I'm afraid that if I use a callback approach I'll get the data back, but it won't update just like my nested get.then. didn't update.

Here is my full factory:

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])

.factory('DataModel', function($http) {

    var days = {};
    var todaysFlavorIndex = 32;
    var todaysFlavorName = [32, 'Loading ...', "vanilla_chocolate_chip.jpg"];
    var daysLeftCalendar = [];

    var flavors = [];

    // calendar objects
    $http.get("https://jsonblob.com/api/5544b8667856ef9baaac1")
        .then(function(response) {
            var result = response.data;
            days = result.Days;

            var dateObj = new Date();
            var day = dateObj.getDate();

            var endOfMonthDate = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), dateObj.getMonth(), 0).getDate();
            for (var di = day; di <= endOfMonthDate; di++) {
                var flavor = days[di - 1];
                daysLeftCalendar.push(flavor[1]);
            }

            var todaysFlavorIndex = -1;
            // $scope.$watch('todaysFlavorIndex', function() {
            //    // Http request goes here
            //    alert('updating !');
            // });
            for (var i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
                if ((days[i])[0] == day) {
                    todaysFlavorIndex = (days[i])[1];
                }
            }

            // flavors
            $http.get("https://jsonblob.com/api/55450c5658d3aef9baac1a")
                .then(function(resp) {
                    flavors = resp.data.flavors;
                    todaysFlavorName = flavors[todaysFlavorIndex];
                });
        }); // end then

    return {
        getDays: function() {
            return days;
        },
        getMonth: function() {
            return days;
        },
        getFlavors: function() {
            return flavors;
        },
        getTodaysFlavorIndex: function() {
            return todaysFlavorIndex;
        },
        getTodaysFlavorName: function() {
            return todaysFlavorName; // flavors[todaysFlavorIndex];
        },
        today: function() {
            var dateObj = new Date();
            var day = dateObj.getUTCDate();
            return todaysFlavorIndex;
        },
        remainingFlavorIndexes: function() {
            return daysLeftCalendar
        }
    };
})
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [angular ionic fails to update for some variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32534353/angular-ionic-fails-to-update-for-some-variables)

Answer (score 9):

**Firstly** , services has no `$scope`.

So injecting scope in factory will always throw you exceptions.

**Secondly** , try to catch callback from controller instead of factory

Try like this

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])

.factory('DataModel', function($http) {

    return {

        myFunction: function() {
            return $http.get("https://jsonblob.com/api/5544b8667856ef9baaac1");
        }

    }

})

.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, DataModel) {

    DataModel.myFunction().then(function(result) {
        // success 
        // put your code here
    }, function(e) {
        // error
    });

})
```

**Thirdly**, If you wanna have inner `$http` you can use [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

Try like this

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])

.factory('DataModel', function($http) {

    return {

        myFunction: function() {
            return $http.get("https://jsonblob.com/api/5544b8667856ef9baaac1");
        },
        myFunction2: function() {
            return $http.get("https://jsonblob.com/api/55450c5658d3aef9baac1a");
        }

    }

})

.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, DataModel, $q) {

    $q.all([
        DataModel.myFunction(),
        DataModel.myFunction2()
    ]).then(function(data) {
        console.log(data[0]); // data from myFunction
        console.log(data[1]); // data from myFunction2
    });

});
```

Comment: The 'no $scope in services' helps a lot. Thanks for showing me two ways to tackle this. When I try doing the then() from the controller I get: "TypeError: DataModel.getDays(...).then is not a function" ... but you can see from my code (above) it is a function.

Comment: @micahhoover can you put it on plunkr or jsfiddle and provide a link for me ?

Comment: Since it's rolled in with Ionic, you might not be able to easily reproduce, but here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/hcjfm22m/

Comment: DataModel.getDays() has no callbacks. then only work in callback